# Ubuntuone: synchronism failure

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have 2 PCs with Ubuntu 12.04 and I have had problems with syncronization of the files. When I modify a file or when I try to connect it my UbuntuOne don't make the synchronism and show me the message: (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED)).
How do I do to fix it?

Thanks,
Vinícius.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Ubuntuone for anything vital. I wish it were as reliable as, say, Dropbox, but that hasn't been my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and this worked for me:

1. Open System > Preferences > Passwords And Encryption Keys (application is called seahorse)
2. Right-click on entries with any of the names below and select Delete:

   1. Ubuntuone token for https://ubuntuone.com
   2. Ubuntu One
3. Open System > Preferences > Ubuntu One
4. Click on the Devices tab and click Restart

Comment: Thanks Dusan! Now, it's ok! I found a link about it: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-should-i-do-if-authentication-fails-auth_failed-state/

Comment: I'm always glad to help when I can! :D